# IIS : rule works as Redirect but not as Rewrite

Tags: iis

I have a custom rewriting provider written in .Net and integrated in IIS 10.

I created a rule using this provider.

The rule works fine as Redirect but doesn't work as Rewrite. I thought they were symmetrical.

[image]

The previous rule works properly and redirects to : https://www.example.com/ords/f?p=app:prdt:7636430122425:NO:P20_SHORTNAME:Token

Then I change only the action type to rewrite :

[image]

Everything is absolutely the same.

When checking the logs, I see that the redirection rewrite removes the question mark and replace it by a space.

https://www.example.com/ords/f**?**p=app:prdt:7636430122425:NO:P20_SHORTNAME:Token

Does anyone know how to solve that please ?

Thanks
Cheers,

Comment: If rewrite operation gives you 404, then clearly you hit mistake 3 in https://blog.lextudio.com/the-very-common-mistakes-when-using-iis-url-rewrite-module-a2ab7e4fee59

Comment: could you please provide your custom rewrite provide and the failed request tracing logs? try to test the URL with the pattern in the URL rewrite pattern test. also enable the proxy by using Application Request Routing [image](https://i.imgur.com/z9yIGHl.png)